# Calculating State And Sales Tax

Tags: java

A program that will ask the user to enter the amount of a purchase. The program should then compute the state sales tax and county sales tax. Assume the state sales tax is 4% and the county sales tax is 2%. The program should display the amount of the purchase, the state sales tax, the county sales tax, the total tax, and total cost of the purchase.

id like to know if i did this correctly or does it need some changes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double Purchaseamount= 30; 
double Statetax = 4.00;
double Countytax = 2.00;
double sum, totalcost;  

    //Calculate total tax
    Statetax=(Statetax/100.0);
    Countytax=(Countytax/100.0); 
    sum = Statetax + Countytax;
    totalcost = Purchaseamount + sum; 

    //Display the following output
    System.out.print("Enter the Purchase amount ");
    System.out.println(Purchaseamount);
    System.out.print("Purchase amount: $");
    System.out.println(Purchaseamount);
    System.out.print("State tax: $");
    System.out.println(Statetax);
    System.out.print("County tax: $");
    System.out.println(Countytax);
    System.out.print("Total tax: $");
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.print("Total coast: $");
    System.out.println(totalcost); 
}
```

Comment: Side note: In Java, variable names should begin with a lowercase letter and camel case (so `StateTax` should be `stateTax`). Otherwise it makes it hard to determine at a glance what is a class (which does begin with an uppercase letter), and a variable.

Comment: Well, that program does not take any user input... so... no? Also, `totalcost = Purchaseamount + sum` should be `totalcost = Purchaseamount * (sum + 1.0)`. To calculate Total cost you have to mulitply by the tax rate. The + 1 is to ensure that the multiplication includes the initial value of the purchase amount.

Comment: Logic seems to be fine, lines can be reduced, but looks fine at the end. But as mentioned, try to use conventions in your code (variables in lower camel case). Additionally, if you are expecting user input, you should include a Scanner or some mechanism for the user to input the purchase value

Comment: all helpful, i forgot to ask, the state tax given was 4% and county tax was 2%, I'm not sure how i could format the percentage.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: "id like to know if i did this correctly" - Is there a reason you can't check this? What happened when you ran the code?

Comment: i felt a little dumb because I never really knew how to calculate tax so i just wanted to know if my calculation was done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic, I think you have to change this block of code:

```
//Calculate total tax
Statetax=(Statetax/100.0);
Countytax=(Countytax/100.0); 
sum = Statetax + Countytax;
totalcost = Purchaseamount + sum;
```

To something like:

```
//Calculate total tax
Statetax = Purchaseamount *(Statetax/100.0);
Countytax = Purchaseamount *(Countytax/100.0); 
sum = Statetax + Countytax;
totalcost = Purchaseamount + sum;
```

This way the variables `Statetax` and `Countytax` are set with the money value relative to your `Purchaseamount` variable.

So, it is going to make more sense with the code you are using to show your data.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks ok, but transactional sales tax is usually more complicated than just State and County tax. You'd have to take into account taxability, jurisdiction and special rules.

Ideally you should use sales tax services like Avalara, TaxJar, Taxcloud and others to obtain an accurate sales tax amount. Most of these services have REST based APIs that are simple to call and return detailed tax breakdown.

As for your other question about formatting the percentage, you could use this code.

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%.0f%%",Statetax))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank youuu! as for the tax thing this is what was assigned to me just to use the state and county tax.